# How to test this kind of API, very secure but hard to test

Tags: unit-testing, security, testing, aws-api-gateway

Our Amazon Web Services (AWS) platform employs Cognito's OAUTH2.0 to engender a session of JWT token, possessing a duration of one hour. Subsequently, this token is transmuted into a five-minute session AWS credential, which is utilized to access the API (configured in AWS Gateway). My inquiry pertains to the methodology for testing this authentication process with a modicum of simplicity. Currently, we are conducting tests utilizing cURL, a technique that has proven to be less than efficacious.

So I just wonder if there are some already done tech stack to help me test my API without too much headache..

OAUTH2.0 ---> JWT token ---> AWS credential ---> API GET/POST/...